# Using AWS lambda to run spring boot project

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a business requirement in which I need a microservice which takes a list of CSV files and use those files to update the Database to which it is connected to. This happens once a month and there is no end point and running of service is not required. The app starts and does the job of creating DB using some CSV files and it's done.

Can I use AWS lambda for it? I already have a spring boot project created which does this job. But we want to minimise the cost and instead of running service in EC2 which is not required because the app only needs to start once a month. I need the best way to do my job with minimum cost.

Ps- DB will also reside in AWS

Comment: Depends. Can your task be done in 15 minutes? Is the CSV file greater then 500MB? What is the source of the CSV? Is it uploaded to S3 once per month, or you want to manually invoke lambda to get the file?

Comment: Lambda supports custom runtimes, so in theory - you can run anything as lambda https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html Another idea: Create for example a step machine which runs the ec2 instance and terminates it after the job is done. If the task runs over 15 minutes, you can also use the step machine to split it into multiple lambda calls. You can use a lambda to split it as well.

Comment: look into what @Marcin said, and you have quoted about `No endpoint` so mix with `Cloud watch Event`, in case if the process is going to be long  take a look at `AWS Batch`, I have actually implemented a project some thing similar to you requirement using AWS Batch and it was quite good.